# crontab -e seems to not show crontabs

Tags: macos, cron

When I do `crontab -l`, I can see my crontabs listed. However, if I do `crontab -e`, it opens a blank file in `mvim`. I also checked to see if /etc/crontab exists, but no such file exists. If this file doesn't exist, where could crontab -l be getting the crontabs from?

**Solved**
I had the `EDITOR` environment variable set to mvim, and for whatever reason, `mvim` didn't open my crontabs. I changed it back to vim and it now works as expected.

Comment: Does it work better if the `EDITOR` and/or `VISUAL` environment variables are unset or set to `/usr/bin/vi`?

Comment: The per-user crontabs are stored in /usr/lib/cron/tabs/<username>

Comment: Ken: I just changed the EDITOR environment variable back from mvim to vim and now it works as expected. Guess the editor was the problem. Will update the original post. Thanks!